# hammer.js - preventing drag event until previous event ended

Tags: javascript, drag, hammer.js

I have a simple photo gallery that change image on drag event, I'm having a problem with iOS7 browser, when dragging right or left the drag event is triggered too many times. I tried to add a global variable that tells if the previous event was not ended but I couldn't get it work, I also tried some of hammer.js options but no luck. any idea?

```
    $picWrapper.hammer({}).on("dragright", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        PhotoGallery.Browse.next();
    }).on("dragleft", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        PhotoGallery.Browse.prev();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using swiperight and swipeleft instead, and event.gesture.preventDefault();